# Simulating C# indexer in C++

Tags: c++, indexing

As you know in C# classes we can define an indexr with more than one argument.
But in C++ operator [ ] can accept one argument. Is there a way to wrtie an indexer in C++ with more than one argument?

indexer in C# :

```
public AnyType this[arg1 , arg2 , .....]
{
    get { ... };
    set { ... };
}
```

[ ] operator in C++ :

```
AnyType & operator [] ( arg )
{
   // our code  
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't support an indexer with more than one argument either.  That was changed for version 4.0, but only for COM interop.

Comment: @HansPassant C# will happily let you do `this[params object[] args]` though. Not sure if that's new but technically it should be one argument at a lower level.

Comment: Also, I'm not overly familiar with C++, but maybe you could do something unbelievably terrible like make the indexer accept a tuple/sequence object argument, and overload the comma operator to automatically construct this tuple. (I'm... 65% sure this is possible, 100% percent sure that I have no idea how you would do it, and 110% sure that people would probably beat you up for globally overloading comma for any parameter type.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a temporary, which holds the first index and has a reference the data source.

```
private:
    class BoundArg {
    private:
        Data& data;
        size_t i; 
    public:
        BoundArg (etc.)

        value_type& operator [] ( size_t j ) {
           return data.get ( i, j );
        }
    };

public:
value_type& get ( size_t i, size_t j ) ...

BoundArg operator [] ( size_t i )
{
   return BoundArg ( *this, i );
}
```

Usually it's not worth the complexity, unless you've got a 2D array stored as a 1D array, in which case the temporary is just a pointer to somewhere into the array.

```
public:
value_type& get ( size_t i, size_t j ) { 
   return data_ [ i * rowWidth_ + j ];
}

value_type* operator [] ( size_t i )
{
   return data_ + i * rowWidth_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately the `[]` operator in C++ only takes one argument.  The best you can do to approximate a multiple argument syntax is to overload the `()` operator.  This approach is used by the matrix class in the Boost linear algebra library so you can lookup by `(row, column)`.

An alternative approach is to have the `[]` operator return a proxy class which also has an overloaded `[]` operator, allowing for syntax like `my_object[0][1]`.  This is similar to the syntax you would get with native C N-dimensional arrays.

Comment: He could also overload the [] operator for pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::pair`, [`std::tuple`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Tuple_types) or [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) as `operator[]`'s argument to achieve effectively the same thing.