# Efficiently simulating C#-style indexer for data which isn't stored as returnable lvalue

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm working on a lightweight relocating garbage-collected alternative to string/vector, targeted at embedded systems with small amounts of RAM (under 64K). My intention is that objects be stored in a pool and that C++ code would hold mutable handles to object references. References could be copied from one handle to another, and objects would continue to exist as long as any reference exists.  Creating, assigning, and destroying handles would be cheap, as would their storage cost (two bytes in the C++ world, plus two bytes in the pool).

If all access to string or vector data were done via methods that copied data between from a static buffer into a pool object, from a pool object to a static buffer, or from one pool object to another, then the facts that objects might move between one method call and the next, or that array elements might be stored non-consecutively in RAM, would be transparent to the caller.  On the other hand, code could be more readable if it could use array-style syntax for accessing elements of vectors.

Allowing the use of array-style syntax only to read elements would be easy; simply copy the data from the pool and return the copy.  Allowing write access, however, seems harder.  The question [Simulating C# indexer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173224/simulating-c-sharp-indexer-in-c) suggests having the `[]` operator return a proxy object, which could then return a reference to the underlying data.  That could fail badly, however, if an object got relocated between the time a reference was created and the time it was used.

An approach which would seem reasonable for handling cases like `foo[i] += 3;` but not so well for `x=foo[i];` would be to have the proxy object copy the array element to a field when constructed, and write that element back to the underlying array when destructed.  While read/modify/write behavior isn't quite the same as by-reference behavior, I would have no qualm about saying that a statement like `foo[23] += bar();` will only have a defined meaning if `bar` doesn't modify `foo[23]`.  Unfortunately, I don't know any way to have a statement like `x = foo[i];` simply read the value of `foo` and not write anything back while still allowing `foo[i] += 3;`.  Is there any nice way to make uses of `foo[i]` which could behave as rvalues do so, while still being able to use `foo[i]` as an lvalue using read/modify/write semantics?

Comment: "lightweight relocating garbage-collected"  HAHAHAHAHA!

Comment: More seriously, have you looked at `std::shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: Why would you write on destruct though?  Why not write when assigning?  I fail to see why you're switching to the read/modify/write behavior.

Comment: Allowing relocatable data will require more memory overhead than you have listed: another two bytes on the heap at minimum, or compiler support.  Since there's no compiler support... you have to do it manually:  A non-relocatable object that is itself a pointer to the relocating object, which means there's _also_ a (tiny) performance penalty.  And since each heap allocation _itself_ also requires additional overhead...

Comment: @MooingDuck: I figure the cost as a 16-bit integer outside the pool to identify an index within the pool's table of handles.  If the pool itself is 64K or less, each handle needs a two-byte offset within the pool to find the start of each object.  If objects have a minimum size of three bytes, and the first byte is never 0xFF, then objects which get moved can be replaced by three-byte relocation records [0xFF plus the new offset].  This data layout may not be quite ideal from a speed perspective, but nowadays a lot of embedded systems are tight on RAM but are faster than they "need to be".

Comment: @MooingDuck: By my estimation, therefore, the total cost of one variable holding a string up to 63 bytes would be length+5 bytes or maybe +6, depending upon whether I pad things to halfword boundaries]; additional variables holding that string would cost 4 bytes each.  I don't think any "normal" string implementation on the ARM would come close for strings with a variety of lengths.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If the type is only used for strings, writing on assignment would be fine; it would be handy to also have it be usable for integers and small PODS. Having to say `temp=foo[3]; temp+=23; foo[3]=temp;` seems a little annoying, as does having to have the indexer overload every single kind of assignment operator. Further, even if every assignment operator is overloaded, I still can't help but think there should be some way to have `x=foo[3];` get evaluated by simply fetching the third item from `foo`, rather than by constructing an indexer object and then converting that to x's type.

Comment: I don't see why you think write on assignment would fail for integers or small pods.  Simply make a template overload of `operator+=` and such.  They're one line each, a tiny amount of code compared to the GC.  As for `x=foo[3]`, trust the optimizer.  It will do exactly what you want under the covers.